# Using cell properties while using sumif() in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to use properties of the cells being summed in the sumif() criteria?

For example, if the values 1, 2, 4, 7, 5 were in cells A1-A5, respectively, would it be possible to sum up only the numbers equal to their respective rows? In that case, only 1, 2, and 5 would be summed to get 8.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula along these lines and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A10=ROW(A1:A10),A1:A10))
```

Or, as a non-array formula that can be confirmed with just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10,--(A1:A10=ROW(A1:A10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

While array formulas can be used to do this, it's much easier to use a helper column for advanced cases.

For example, in cells B1-B5 you could write a formula that checks the whether the value is equal to the row. For cell B1:

```
=IF(A1=ROW(),A1,0)
```

Then drag this down to fill B1-B5. Then you can simply sum these values instead.

Alternatively, if you are using `SUMIFS` with multiple conditions, you may use `=A1=ROW()` for cell B1 and use the column B as one of the conditions. Then the sum could be `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,TRUE)`